# Cannot listen file in logstash with absolute path

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I have logstash installed on path: D:\WORK\ElasticSearch\logstash-2.0.0\bin
and my apps write logs on path: D:\Logs

When I use logstash path to load logs "D:\WORK\ElasticSearch\logstash-2.0.0\bin" with this script i'm able to read it.

`input
{
    file 
    {
        path => ["\PlatformTest_*"]
        #discover_interval - How often (in seconds) we expand the filename patterns in the path option to discover new files to watch
        discover_interval => 20
        #start_position - Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning or at the end
        start_position => "beginning"
        #stat_interval - How often (in seconds) we stat files to see if they have been modified. 
        stat_interval => 2
    }
}`

But when I use the real path of logs with this log, it don't work:

`input 
{
    file 
    {
        path => ["D:\Logs\PlatformTest_*"]
        #discover_interval - How often (in seconds) we expand the filename patterns in the path option to discover new files to watch
        discover_interval => 20
        #start_position - Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning or at the end
        start_position => "beginning"
        #stat_interval - How often (in seconds) we stat files to see if they have been modified. 
        stat_interval => 2
    }
}`

Also when I try relative path it don't work:

`input 
{
    file 
    {
        path => ["\..\..\..\..\Logs\PlatformTest_*"]
        #discover_interval - How often (in seconds) we expand the filename patterns in the path option to discover new files to watch
        discover_interval => 20
        #start_position - Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning or at the end
        start_position => "beginning"
        #stat_interval - How often (in seconds) we stat files to see if they have been modified. 
        stat_interval => 2
    }
}`

Any Idea?

Comment: could you check the permission of the file which you are trying to read ? Also just make sure it has the right group

Comment: the permission was ok. thanks for the idea!

Comment: Turn up debugging in logstash and it should tell you what it thinks about the path you've given it.  It's probably a typo or a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using forward slashes instead of backslashes.

```
input 
{
    file 
    {
        path => ["D:/Logs/PlatformTest_*"]
        #discover_interval - How often (in seconds) we expand the filename patterns in the path option to discover new files to watch
        discover_interval => 20
        #start_position - Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning or at the end
        start_position => "beginning"
        #stat_interval - How often (in seconds) we stat files to see if they have been modified. 
        stat_interval => 2
    }
}
```